# Whether the file opencv2/text.hpp was exist?

Tags: opencv3.0

I was begin to study OCR thr A demo program of the Extremal Region Filter algorithm described in * Neumann L., Matas J.: Real-Time Scene Text Localization and Recognition, CVPR 2012.
But I found no header file opencv2/text.hpp after searched in OpenCV included file.
My question:the file opencv2/text.hpp was exist or not?

Answer (score 2):

I also couldn't find this file in OpenCV directories. But I found this file in github repository of Itseez here: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/text/include/opencv2. Check this link if it contains what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You have to build your opencv with extra modules on . The modules folder can be obtained from cloning opencv_contrib repo on github

Answer (score 0):

You can find opencv2/text.hpp  [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib)